# Firebase Swift 3 Error in Type Casting

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

Receiving some errors while retrieving data from Firebase.

Here is my code:

```
//  MARK:- Pull in data from Firebase on the main thread. READ ONLY ONCE.
self.ref.child("Power_Stations").child("Stations").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {     snapshot in
if snapshot.exists() {
    for item in snapshot.children {
        let x = item as! FIRDataSnapshot
        let name = x.value(forKey: "Power_Station_Name") as Any
        print(name)
    }
}
```

})

**Problem**: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Power_Station_Name.' <- This is happening at

```
let name = x.value(forKey:"Power_Station_name") as Any
```

The above error is telling me that i'm getting an crash when it is attempting to fill a variable with a particular value?

However, when I print the data this is what i'm receiving in the logs:

```
Snap (-KXRfS0afUet-U8r996p) {
"Power_Station_Address" = nil;
"Power_Station_City" = nil;
"Power_Station_ID" = VsNggVo;
"Power_Station_Inventory" =     {
    android = 12;
    "android_description" = "Fully Stocked";
    ios = 6;
    "ios_description" = "Fully Stocked";
};
"Power_Station_Lat" = "33.6000422";
"Power_Station_Long" = "23.228643";
"Power_Station_Name" = "Power Pods Station";
"Power_Station_Owner" = "Power Pods Inc.";
"Power_Station_Rating" =     {
    "Average_Ranking" = "4.5";
    "Number_Of_Ratings" = 105;
};
"Power_Station_State" = nil;
"Power_Station_Update_Date" = "2016-11-25 18:09:46 +0000";
"Power_Station_Upload_Date" = "2016-11-25 18:09:46 +0000";
```

}

Below is how i am saving data to the database.

```
let newObject = [
                        "Power_Station_ID" : id,
                        "Power_Station_Name" : "Power Pods Station" as String,
                        "Power_Station_Address" : "\(placeMark.thoroughfare)" as String,
                        "Power_Station_City" : "\(placeMark.locality)" as String,
                        "Power_Station_State" : "\(placeMark.administrativeArea)" as String,
                        "Power_Station_Long" : (placeMark.location?.coordinate.longitude)! as Double,
                        "Power_Station_Lat" : (placeMark.location?.coordinate.latitude)! as Double,
                        "Power_Station_Owner" : "Power Pods Inc." as String,
                        "Power_Station_Inventory" : [
                            "ios" : 6,
                            "ios_description" : "Fully Stocked" as String,
                            "android" : 12,
                            "android_description" : "Fully Stocked" as String
                            ] as [String : Any],
                        "Power_Station_Rating" : [
                            "Number_Of_Ratings" : 105,
                            "Average_Ranking" : 4.5,
                            ] as [String : Any],
                        "Power_Station_Upload_Date" : String(describing: NSDate()),
                        "Power_Station_Update_Date" : String(describing: NSDate())
                    ] as [String : Any]

                    self.ref.child("Power_Stations").child("Stations").childByAutoId().setValue(newObject)
```

Can anyone help me identify what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a little more code that defines the snapshot.value as a Dictionary of [String:String] (or String:Any). The value needs to have that definition as it could be a String, or NSNumber etc.

```
let x = item as! FIRDataSnapshot
let dict = x.value! as! [String:String]
let powerStation = dict["Power_Station_Name"]!
```

Comment: thank you @Jay ... I also used the following code.

x.childSnapshot(forPath: "Power_Station_Address").value

and it also worked. Do you know why or if this is the official change now for pulling the data from Firebase. I've used firebase before but never pulled data from it like the above.

Comment: Remember that when reading Firebase .values can be strings, numbers, another dictionary or the dreaded array (please don't use arrays) so only you know what you are expecting so you need to define what it is supposed to be in code. If the answer worked, don't forget to to accept it!